# Is a terms filter by keyword better that a date_range when matching exact days?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find out which way is better to query, but my tests do not yield conclusive results, probably because I cannot generate enough data locally.

Consider this mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "day": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyyMMdd",
          "fields": {
              "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
              }
          }
        },
        ... other stuff ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When looking for a continuous date range (like from 20191001 to 20191010) I can either use `terms` or `date_range`, which has more advantages in terms of performance, caching or memory usage ?

### Using `terms` :

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
          { 
            "terms" : { 
              "day.keyword" : [ 
                "20191001", 
                "20191002", 
                "20191003",
                "20191004", 
                "20191005", 
                "20191006",
                "20191007", 
                "20191008", 
                "20191009",
                "20191010"
              ] 
            }
          } 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Using `date_range`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "day": {
              "gte": "20191001",
              "lte": "20191010"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the scenario where you want to pick data between Jan'17 to Jan'19. You have to specify all the dates in terms query. As you range increases your input also increases.

As the name suggests, range query is to query records specified between a continuous range.

Terms query is mainly to search for a specific/exact term in a document.